# Different authorizations for different pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My question is rather naive and I apologize for that .My web config file for a restricted access folder is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Member" />
            <allow roles="Admin" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now this applies to all the pages in the folder,is there a way I can modify it such that any user with the role Member will have access to say only members.aspx while Admin will have access to a whole bunch of pages .

I guess I could do it by creating different folders and storing different pages in the them and assigning the webconfig as needed but I was wondering if it was possible to have page level authorization (based on roles) in a single folder

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify access to different specific URLs in your site by using [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) elements. Note that you can configure all locations from your parent web.config; having multiple web.config files for this is not necessary.

```
    
  <location path="members.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Member" />
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="adminsonly.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Although multiple web.configs aren't needed I prefer to keep the authorization settings as close to the pages as possible. It makes it far easier to maintain.